# freebaseapps reconciliation stuck in Open Refine 2.6

Tags: openrefine

I have some small test data with the names of 10 actors, that I would like to expand with some additional data.

[image: screen shot 2016-01-16 at 3 06 23 pm]

This used to work fine using this reconciliation service: http://reconcile.freebaseapps.com/reconcile. However, now it is stuck there. Is there any problem with the service?

[image: screen shot 2016-01-16 at 3 07 36 pm]

[image: screen shot 2016-01-16 at 3 04 55 pm]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google deprecated freebase on December 2015, this is why the service is not working anymore. You can [read the announcement here](https://plus.google.com/u/0/109936836907132434202/posts/iY8NZGFF6DN?cfem=1).